# Javascript Array in Class = How to make it valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am using [this jQuery validation library](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) on my website.  It requires me to put the validation rules in the class part of the input tag.  ie `<input class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]]" name="firstname" type="text" />`

Now this causes me to end up with code in mine that looks similar such as:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="charfname" 
       name="charfname" 
       value=""  
       style="width: 300px;" 
       class="validate[required,length[3,20],custom[noSpecialCaracters]]" />
```

Which as you see has a [ and ] in the class name.  So when I run the page through a validator I get the error:

> character "[" is not allowed in the value of attribute "class"

How do I fix this to make it valid but still have the library work?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're asking "how can I use invalid markup and still have my page validate" :-)

Comment: What doctype are you using? What validator? With W3C's validator (http://validator.w3.org/), I get no error mentioning "[" as an illegal character. Square brackets would be problematic for CSS selectors, but you're not using the class for CSS, so that's not a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Use some other method for initialization or use another script? Use an alternate attribute and a custom DTD for example. Or throw away the attribute based init system and use something else. Either way you have to modify the plugin's code. You cannot use "[" and "]" characters in a class name and any other combination implying them, period.